# unix copy hidden and nonhidden one copy command

Tags: unix

I understand how to copy a hidden folder:

```
cp ./[^.]stringmatch /destination
```

and I understand how to copy a nonhidden folder

```
cp *stringmatch /desination
```

But how do I copy both hidden and nonhidden files with a particular stringmatch?

Answer (score 2):

Try `cp {.,}*stringmatch* /destination`... Hope that helps!

Comment: This did not work.  None of the files starting with . were copied over.

Comment: Better now? it's a shell thing... in `zsh` the './' makes no difference